# Optional parameters in MVC3 routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create routes which can apply 1 and 2 type of URLs.

1 - First route will be at the start of application and I want 2 type of URLs that can used to access index page. I cannot hit below route when I have URL with Home at the end instead going to type 2.

```
http://www.example.com Or http://www.example.com/Home

routes.MapRoute(
               "Default",
               "{controller}/{action}",
               new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = "" }
           );
```

2 - This type of URL is passing "Name" parameter to load contents from DB. I want this URL like

http://www.example.com/Page?name=Contact Or

http://www.example.com/Page?name=Contact&id=22

But I want above URL like

http://www.example.com/Contact Or http://www.example.com/About

Or

http://www.example.com/Contact/22 Or http://www.example.com/About/33

Where
Contact and About are values for "Name" parameter passed in URL. Below is the Route used

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "DynamicPages",
                "{name}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Page" }
            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. I am not sure if this is the right way to do this.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //To match http://www.mysite.com
    routes.MapRoute(
        "RootUrl",
        "",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    //To match http://www.mysite.com/Home
    routes.MapRoute(
        "RootUrlWithAction",
        "Home/{action}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );

    //To match http://www.mysite.com/Contact Or 
    //      http://www.mysite.com/About Or
    //      http://www.mysite.com/Contact/22 Or
    //      http://www.mysite.com/About/33
    routes.MapRoute(
        "DynamicPages",
        "{name}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Page", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    // Everything else
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Tested the following routes. Here the site root url is **http://localhost:5879/**. Refer the output screenshots provided below for each of the below mentioned scenario.

1. http://localhost:5879/  --> Uses **first** route map
2. http://localhost:5879/Home  --> Uses **second** route map
3. http://localhost:5879/Contact --> Uses **third** route map
4. http://localhost:5879/About/33 --> Uses **third** route map
5. http://localhost:5879/Home/Page?name=Contact&id=22 --> Uses **third** route map
6. http://localhost:5879/Home/Index/2 --> Uses **fourth** route map

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: Scenario 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: Scenario 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: Scenario 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: Scenario 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: Scenario 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: Scenario 6]

Hope that gives you some idea to solve your issue.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. Let me run some tests and I get back to you.